# Images from YouTube links are shown in Opera Mini even when "Load images" is off

Tags: opera-mini

I use Opera Mini with "Load images" set to off when browsing on mobile data, to speed it up and save bandwidth. This removes most images, however, I've noticed that whenever there is a link to a YouTube video, a still frame will still be loaded and shown.

I assume this maybe is because those are considered HTML video tags, and hence are treated differently?

In any event, is it possible to turn those off, too? Some other setting (I looked but didn't find any, but maybe I just missed it).

Comment: I think your assumption is right. If they are in Video tags then they aren't 'images' in the sense of jpgs etc. This would happen with other formats, for example Flash that will load even with images blocked also.